# how to write date in this format in c#

Tags: c#

i have a date   `9/27/2010 8:17:28 PM`  i want to write them in this format like `27 september 2010 8:19 PM` how i can write in this format using c#

Comment: 8:19?... er, rounding error there possibly

Comment: http://john-sheehan.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/msnet-formatting-strings.pdf

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use a [custom DateTime format string](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx):

```
string res = myDate.ToString("d MMMM yyyy h:mm tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Update:

As [@Jon Hanna](https://stackoverflow.com/users/400547/jon-hanna) mentions, this will format the month with title case (`September`), so if you want it exactly as in your example (`september`), you can add a `ToLowerInvariant()` method call.

Comment: MMMM with InvariantCulture gives a title-cased string, so you'll want to add a ToLowerInvariant() to get the format in the question.

Answer (score 2):

Check [Custom Date and Time Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx) on msdn.